# Rails not reloading on each request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, configuration

I can not for the life of me figure out what the problem is here. Sometimes when I generate an app reloading works and sometimes it doesn't. But once it does not work (for a specific project). It never works for that project. Ive even moved the code across different machines with the same effect. So it must be some kind of configuration issue but I can not figure out where

This is my development.rb (I also made sure its running in development mode)

```
EpochApp::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = false
  config.eager_load = false
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load
  config.assets.debug = true
end
```

Ive also tried using "Thin" which has the same problem.

Views reload fine, but controllers and helpers do not at all without a server reboot. Ive seen it mentioned that turning on threadsafe forces cache_classes on... So the only other thing I could think is a gem might be forcing it on, but I really dont have any crazy gems enabled; mostly just JS inclusion gems

```
  gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
  gem 'mysql2'
  gem 'bcrypt-ruby'
  gem "aws-ses"
  gem 'stripe'
  gem 'compass-rails', github: 'milgner/compass-rails', branch: 'rails4'
  gem 'anjlab-bootstrap-rails', :require => 'bootstrap-rails', :github => 'anjlab/bootstrap-rails', :branch => '3.0.0'
  gem 'font-awesome-rails'
  gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails', :require => 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-datepicker-rails.git'
  gem "american_date"
  gem 'bootstrap-timepicker-rails', :require => 'bootstrap-timepicker-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/tispratik/bootstrap-timepicker-rails.git'
  gem 'faker'
  gem "block_helpers"
  gem "select2-rails"
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
  gem 'jquery-rails'
  gem 'turbolinks'
  gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
  gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
  group :doc do
    gem 'sdoc', require: false
  end
```

I'm out of ideas and its incredibly annoying having to constantly restart the server every 30-40 seconds.

Comment: `config.cache_classes = false.` is that fullstop accidental?

Comment: Sorry yeah. I stripped out all the comments ruby inserts when i posted it, that must of gotten stuck in there. The actual config doesn't have the period/full stop in it.

Comment: Just thought I'd check :)

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem caused by the **turbolinks gem** https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/

Turbolinks will not reload the page every time a request is made, it will keeps the current page "alive" and only replace html, this way, your browser doesn't have to recompile all css and js files. It's way faster when you have a lot of css/js files.

Comment: Darn, at first i thought that was an excellent idea. I removed the gem but it didn't make a difference. Most of the time I am manually reloading the page I'm working on anyway which would bypass turbo link... It was a good idea though. The search continues.

Comment: Might be worth removing then re-adding each gem in turn to see if it's one of them...